# How to count how many listeners are hooked to an event?

Tags: c#, events

Assuming I have declared

```
public event EventArgs<SyslogMessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;

public int SubscribedClients
{
    get [...]
}
```

I would like to count how many "subscribed clients" my class has. I need to sum those that subscribed over network though my APIs (not shown in the fragment) **plus** those that did `channel.MessageReceived+=myMethod;`.

I know that C# events may be declared explicitly with `add` and `remove` statements, and there I can surely count + or -1 to a local counter, but I never wrote code for explicit events in C#, so I don't know exactly what more to perform on add and remove rather than updating the counter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use [`GetInvocationList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.getinvocationlist):

```
MessageReceived?.GetInvocationList().Length
```

Comment: You'd better add a null test.

Comment: No need to do a null test if initialize the event with an empty delegate. However, the count length will be 1. public event EventArgs<SyslogMessageEventArgs> MessageReceived = delegate { };

Comment: 11 years later: I would kindly like to point out that `?.` is a null test in C# (read it as, `if not null`)

Comment: @darkpbj my answer was edited in 2019 :-D so it looks like the comments are out of tune.

Comment: The first comment is still correct. Using .Length will try to return an int, which is not nullable. You will still need a null check before the line getting length.

Comment: @sjoshua270 `x?.y.Length` returns `int?` aka `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
   public event EventArgs<SyslogMessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;

   public int SubscribedClients
   {
       get {
         return (MessageReceived == null)
                ? 0
                : MessageReceived.GetInvocationList().Length
                ;
       }
   } 
}


void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    if(a.SubscribedClients == 0)
    {
        a.MessageReceived += ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `get` can be written as `(MessageReceived?.GetInvocationList().Length ?? 0) == 0)` **-** If the `?` can't be evaluated then the value following the `??` is taken